# Plotting diagram of complex equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, complex, code-review

I have this equation:

```
q1[t_] := -I*γ*Sin[θ] + ((γ*Cos[θ])/n^2)*(I*ξ[t]*y+z*α[t])
```

and the main code is the following with the definition of each parameters:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Remove["Global`*"];

x = 1000;
y = 0;
z = 20;
n = Sqrt[y^2 + z^2];

c = 4000;
Subscript[c, d] = 200;
γ = Subscript[c, d]/c;
ρ = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
θ = Pi/4;
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
x/ρ < γ;
tl = ρ^2/(c*x);
ξ[t_] := c*t - x;
tdc = 1/c*(x + n*Sqrt[1/γ^2 - 1]);
α[t_] := Sqrt[ξ[t]^2 - n^2*(1/γ^2 - 1)];
w0 = (ρ^2*γ^2/x^2 - 1)*(z^2*(Cos[θ])^2)/n^2;
q1[t_] := -I*γ*Sin[θ] + ((γ*Cos[θ])/n^2)*(I*ξ[t]*y + z*α[t]);
q2[t_] := -I γ*Sin[θ] + (γ*Cos[θ])/n^2*(I*ξ[t]*y - z*α[t]);
svd = -I*γ*Sin[θ] + I*(y*Cos[θ])/n*(1 - γ^2);

ParametricPlot[{{Re[q1[t]], Im[q1[t]]}}, {t, 0.35, 0.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"q1(t)", "q2(t)"}, AxesLabel -> {"Re(q)", "Im(q)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Complex q-plane plot", PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

The thing about q1[t] is this, that i have a q1[t] and q2[t] which are different in z. q1[t] is z>0 and q2[t] is z<0. There are variables like x,y,z>0 and n and ρ and theta and gamma is defined in the code. gamma is the ratio of dilatational speed to the actual load speed which in my case, load speed is higher than dilatational speed which can be called supersonic case. theta changes from 0 to Pi/2. q1[t] is dependent on ξ and alpha which are defined. When I put tdc amount in q1[t] it gives me svd[t] that I defined. It's just for comparison. when x/ρ < γ, svd is negative and when x/ρ > γ, svd is positive. Now look at the final shape in Gakenheimer thesis:

[image]

This is for the `x/ρ > γ`. Now look at the other picture:

[image]

As you can see, I have these 2 figures and I can't reach the first one that starts from negative imaginary part of W. Note that W in pictures is the q I defined in my code. I tried to get all variables constant and only t (time) the main variable.

Note that at the time tl, q1[t1]=w0. I did also define w0 in the code. Please help me fix it and reach the final figure.

Comment: Ali, I am not sure that your question is appropriate for this site, at least not yet. It does not really focus on a Mathematica problem, but rather it potentially stems from a misunderstanding of the cited work. Replicating those plots likely requires a better understanding of the underlying problem. Unless you happen to find somebody already well-versed with this problem, in my opinion it is unlikely that somebody will go read and understand that dissertation just to fix the plots for you. Therefore I vote to close.

Comment: Incidentally, if somebody is actually interested, the dissertation cited in the question is: Gakenheimer, David Charles (1969). Transient excitation of an elastic half-space by a point load traveling on the surface. California Institute of Technology. doi:10.7907/5FEH-EG57 and it can be found at [https://resolver.caltech.edu/CaltechETD:etd-03022006-134535](https://resolver.caltech.edu/CaltechETD:etd-03022006-134535).